# Bind value attribute from input field to JsViews Observables

Tags: javascript, datepicker, jsrender, jsviews, flatpickr

I am trying to bind the `value=".."`-attribute from an `<input>`-field to a [JsViews](https://www.jsviews.com/#jsobservable) *observable*, so that changes made from a JS datepicker will get detected by the JsView framework.

**Example**

On initial rendering, the data-linked *observedDate* parameter is displayed in the `<input>`-field:

```
<input class="flatpickr-calendar" type="text" data-link="observedDate">
```

Then, selecting a new date using the [flatpickr](https://chmln.github.io/flatpickr/getting-started/) javascript tool, the new date will be stored in the `value=".."`-field:

```
<input class="flatpickr-calendar" type="text" data-link="observedDate" value="2017-05-09">
```

**The problem**

There is now a divergence between the date handled by *observedDate* and the *value*-attribute:

***JsViews does not detect the change in the value-attribute.***

---

Does anyone have some suggestion as of how to handle this situation? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an event [onChange](https://chmln.github.io/flatpickr/events/) update value `observedDate`.

For example, you can do so:

```
$(".flatpickr").flatpickr({
    onChange: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
        $.observable($.view(this.input).data).setProperty("observedDate", dateStr);
    },
});
```

[full code](https://jsfiddle.net/Coddwrench/bpoa45mt/1/).

### Update

Or you can create custom tag:

```
$.views.tags({
    flatpickr: {
        template: "<input/>",
        onUpdate: false,
        dataBoundOnly: true,

        flatpickr: null,
        isChange: false,
        changeEvent: function (selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
            this.isChange = true;
            this.update(dateStr);
            this.isChange = false;
        },

        onDispose: function () {
            if (this.flatpickr) {
                this.flatpickr.destroy();
            }
        },

        onAfterLink: function (tagCtx, linkCtx) {
            var tag = this;
            var props = tagCtx.props;
            var options = {
                defaultDate: tagCtx.args[0]
            };

            if (tag._.unlinked) {
                if (!tag.linkedElem) {
                    tag.linkedElem = tag._.inline ? tag.contents("*").first() : $(linkCtx.elem);
                }
                $.each(props, function (key, prop) {
                    var option;
                    if (key.charAt(0) === "_") {
                        key = key.slice(1);
                        options[key] = prop;
                    }
                });

                options.onChange = $.proxy(tag.changeEvent, tag);
                this.flatpickr = tag.linkedElem.flatpickr(options);
            } else {
                if (!this.isChange) {
                    this.flatpickr.setDate(options.defaultDate)
                }
            }
        }

    }
});
```

And use:

```
{^{flatpickr observedDate /}}
```

[full code](https://jsfiddle.net/Coddwrench/xj7tug66/1/)

Support flatpickr [options](https://chmln.github.io/flatpickr/options/):

```
{^{flatpickr observedDate _inline=true _maxDate='2018-05-01' _minDate='2017-05-01'/}}
```

[full code](https://jsfiddle.net/Coddwrench/xj7tug66/2/)

Comment: Great example, thanks! I still haven't gotten around the custom tags concept, and this was a nice use case example, I think. :-)